# How to load SQL Server DB into dataset?

Tags: c#

I want to load the entire database (SQL Server) I have into a dataset so that I can work with several tables and their relationships. I know this might be frowned upon, but how  can I do this (I will be using DataRelation and Table objects)?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to do this? :P

Comment: Not sure why you'd want to do this, but I'd iterate through the list of tables and populate a DataTable with the contents. I'd also expect you to run out of memory first.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something this should just be a simple case of generating a dataset and then altering the Fill methods to remove the WHERE portion.  Then ensure you call the fills in the right order (master, then detail) to ensure you maintain the referential integrity.

Comment: Any example of how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can run this... but don't expect to have a db or app server after.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("YourConnectionString"))
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("exec sp_msforeachtable 'select * FROM ?'", conn))
        {
            conn.Open();

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            command.Fill(ds);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Read some article about in memory Database.
2. @ Randolph Potter idea is an option - you can get the list of tables from the server, and then iterate on the list and load all the tables. I guess you can do that same about FK and relations.
3. you can probably do it automatically using the designer - using drag and drop from the server explorer to a dataset (VS2008), and with a little code load the entire thing into memory.

Comment: I asked as the question came about from looking at this: http://www.knowdotnet.com/articles/datarelation.html I guess I can iterate the tables and then load them/use them. DataTable with a name same as the table in the db once I've connected should be a live instance of that table.

Comment: Also, if I am going to work with 2 tables or more, I can do this: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/2/10110718/how-to-load-data-from-dat.aspx but run the method n times for n tables (in a loop or whatever).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could do multiple selects within a single stored procedure and then fill a dataset.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("YourConnectionString"))
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter command = new SqlDataAdapter("usp_YourStoredProcedure", conn))
        {
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            conn.Open();

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            command.Fill(ds);
        }
    }
```

I would agree with the other comments here that unless your database is tiny this is a really bad idea.